# NATS KV history larger than specified when creating bucket

Tags: go, key-value, nats.io

We are using [nats with KeyValue store feature (nats KV)](https://docs.nats.io/using-nats/developer/develop_jetstream/kv). We develop go microservices and use the nats go client. We try to leverage the history feature of nats KV with no success yet.

Certain times using nats, we retrieve a **larger** history than the history specified when creating the KV.

We create the KV using :

```golang
kv, _ := js.CreateKeyValue(&nats.KeyValueConfig{
        Bucket:       "some-bucket",
        Description:  "store for some-service",
        MaxValueSize: 0,
        History:      10, // should we ever get more than 10 elements when reading history ?
        TTL:          TTL,
        MaxBytes:     5000000,
        Storage:      nats.MemoryStorage,
        Replicas:     0,
        Placement:    nil,
    })
```

and we retrieve values using

```
kv.History("someId")
```

When we get results larger than the specified History, we get several `KeyValueEntry`s with the same `delta` value.

We are quite write intensive, and also reuse quite a lot the same key id :

- we write values until a certain point,
- call `kv.Purge("someId")`
- and then we may reuse "someId" later on in the process.

Writes and read are asynchronous and concurrent.

Here is our client go.mod regarding nats:

```
    github.com/nats-io/nats-server/v2 v2.8.4
    github.com/nats-io/nats.go v1.16.0
```

and we run a nats server version 2.8.4.

*note : I did not go far enough in the [KV implementation details](https://github.com/nats-io/nats.go/blob/f4a86f30ce2a7d36cfdb4ceb6669961406ac9f61/kv.go#L763) but I am worried that this is linked with jetstream. It seems like a watcher is created each time and re-reads all previous values regardless of history size. It leads me to another question : is the kv history feature appropriate for read intensive use cases ?*

Thanks for your help or pointers on this matter.